# How to set default value in thymeleaf th:field

Tags: spring, thymeleaf

I have a form and I want to set default value in the field below but it's not working.

```
    <span>ID User:</span>

                <input type="text"   th:value="${session.name}"  th:field="*{userid}" th:errorclass="field-error"  />

            </div>  
            <div>           
                <span class="name-in">ID Room:</span>
                <input type="text"  th:value="${id}"   th:field="*{room}" th:errorclass="field-error" />
            </div>
```

I read some topic about this problem and I try to change as given below

```
th:attr="value = ${session.name}"
```

But It's still not working. Field ID User is empty. I don't know how to solve this problem.

Comment: Just to make it clear, you want to populate your 'userId' field and then send that object further after submit button to next controller.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although your question contain less information, but i think you want to put default  value for all field. If you like to do so change

```
`<input type="text"   th:value="${session.name}"  th:field="*{userid}" th:errorclass="field-error"  />`
```

to

```
<input type="text"   name="userid" value="as your wish" th:errorclass="field-error"  />
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of changing the html, you should instead set the value of `*{userid}` in your controller.  That way you can keep your html the same:

```
// Controller
modelObject.setUserId(session.name);

// HTML
<input type="text" th:field="*{userid}" th:errorclass="field-error"  />
```